# Getting "invalid parameter name" while building lineage 15.1 from source for xiaomi mi a1

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to build lineage 15.1 from source for `tissot` device according to [that guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a1/how-to/guide-build-rom-source-tissot-t3754723) and get an error "invalid parameter name" while running `brunch tissot` which looks axactly as error for cheeseburder i found [on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cv6u8QAU) ([my output](https://pastebin.com/Qs3aQ2fJ)). In subsequent `make` i get an `build stopped: subcommand failed` error. Also i get `Trying dependencies-only mode on a non-existing device tree?` . Is there any way to fix this error?

Answer (score 13):

Figered out that problem in zsh. `setopt shwordsplit`  and `export LC_ALL=C` solved all problems

Comment: if the problem is gone, maybe you should mark your answer as right?